# How to use DataTables with 100000 records?

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

because I`m using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) in my site therefor selected [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) to display my data on the pages. is some cases i have more than 100K records and would like to show them as a 20 records per page in the table , but i do not want to load all the 100k records to the client side, in case just want to load the amount that is needed for each page with JQuery Ajax, how could i implement such scenario with DataTables? all the samples seem to be loading the whole data to the client side !! or maybe i missed it !!

Comment: It's in the documentation: http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: Oooh! I need to change my glasses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Keven B said :

It's in the documentation: [datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)